# Is var the only option we have for declaring global variables and functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, var, let

On this page:

I found that it is important to use var and we can not use let and const for declaring global variables and functions but I tried to do use let and const. So should I use them or they are not recommended?

Here is my code that I ran:

```
let a;
globalThis.a = 3;
console.log(globalThis);
```

and here is the output:

[image]

So you can clearly see a gets added without any error. So should I continue using this or this works but not recommended?

Comment: You have a `Window` object, why is this tagged [tag:node.js]?

Comment: It is tagged nodejs becuase this question is related to every environment in which we run JavaScript.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is this that it is recommended to use var only or there is no such boundation

Comment: There is very little reason to use `var` now*. Always use `let` and `const` if it is supported.

Comment: @TusharVaswani — The behaviour differs between JS in modules (which JS code always is) and outside of modules (which your code in the browser is) so the answers vary.

Comment: There is also a difference between "a global" and "a properly on the window object"

Comment: Ok Thanks @adiga for helping me out. Now i understood the thing.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Quentin for helping me out. Now i understood the thing.

Comment: @Noob Actually there is a difference like lot of the functions in the window objects are not available in the global object.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to shed some light on this. Generally speaking, regardless of the programming language, environment and use case, it is always good practice to keep variables/data scopes as narrow as possible. This is for many reasons spanning from security to simple namespace pollution and code organization.

I see that you are at the beginning of your JavaScript journey. As you'll start creating more complex applications, you'll find patterns that will almost oblige you to keep your variables local. This is achieved by using function scopes in JavaScript.

In a browser, code outside modules and functions (actually they are the same as you'll see) is considered to be in the global scope, which is anyway always accessible using `window` or other syntaxes (`self`, `frames`, `this` sometimes). However, in other environments, like NodeJS, this will not work for two main reasons. The first one is that all the code is executed inside modules. The second reason is that some of the above syntaxes doesn't even exist.

In node, you can use `global` to access the global scope. However, variables created, even with `var`, will always be local because modules are wrapped inside a function like this:

```js
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// Module code actually lives in here
});
```

So, even variables like "exports", "require", "module", "__filename", "__dirname" that seemed global are actually local for each module.

`globalThis` was introduced to create a consistent way of accessing the global scope across multiple environments.

Finally, I recommend you to not use `var`, but `const` and `let` and to organize your code in a way that, ideally, no variable is exposed in the global scope.

Comment: I diidnt understood the first part related to module but i will undersrant it when i learn modules but I udnerstood the second part that var should not be used and I thank you for the answer